# Convert String to Object gives error due to double quotes at start and end

Tags: javascript, json, object

i have an object that is coming from the third party api. and it is in the form like this :

```
"{ "type": "object", "properties": {   "hostUrl": {
    "type": "string",
    "description": "hostUrl",   }, }, }"
```

due to the double quote in the start and the end i am getting error and json parse is also not being removed so kindly tell me how to remove this double quote which has wrapped my object inside it

Comment: In the description of the JSON tag: _"Before you ask a question, validate your JSON using a JSON validator such as JSONLint (https://jsonlint.com)."_ This isn't valid JSON. Ask the maintainer of the third party API to fix it.

Comment: @jabaa Since it is a 3rd party API, rather than requesting them to update their databases, it would be better to find a quick fix at our end.

Comment: @PavanAdityaMS There is no simple, quick fix. You have to parse the string. You need a complex parser that considers all edge cases.

Comment: @jabaa 
It is a normal json object wrongly wrapped inside double quotes(instead of single quotes). So converting it into a string and parsing it with JSON.parse() will cover every edge case.

Comment: @PavanAdityaMS Trailing commas aren't allowed in JSON.

Comment: Can you show the code that you used to get the object?

Comment: @Serge The string comes from a third party API.

Comment: @jabaa I understand this, but how are you getting it?  it is not valid as a string and you can have it the way you posted it  Can you post the real string you've got?

Comment: @Serge How can a string be not valid? You can assume something like: `const str = '"{ "type": "object", "properties": {  "hostUrl": { "type": "string", "description": "hostUrl",   }, }, }"';`

Comment: @jabaa I am sorry I can not guess what OP has. I need a presize string to know how to convert  it in  a valid json.

Comment: i fixed it thanks all for the contribution

Comment: You should add your solution.

Comment: @jabaa yes let me optimize it and then i will share the clean code here in a few

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
const jsonStr =
  '"{ "type": "object", "properties": {  "hostUrl": { "type": "string", "description": "hostUrl",   }, }, }"';

var json = jsonStr
  .substring(1, jsonStr.length - 1)
  .replaceAll("},", "}")
  .replaceAll(" ", "")
  .replaceAll(",}", "}");
```

json

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "hostUrl": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "hostUrl"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should at least mention that your code will modify all strings containing `},` and only work for exactly this example. It's very easy to break your code. It won't work with arrays. Maybe your answer is the correct solution for this question, but I would expect an answer that can handle `"{ "type": "some\"},\"type", "properties": ["a", "b",], }"` without changing `some"},"type`.

Answer (score -1):

//Try this

```
let obj = {key:"{'name':'bhautik','age':24}"}
let a = obj.key
console.log(a)  //it will log: "{'name':'bhautik','age':24}"

a = a.replaceAll('\'', "\"")
console.log(JSON.parse(a))   

output:
[object Object] {
  age: 24,
  name: "bhautik"
}



if still not work then try this

let obj = {key:"{'name':'bhautik','age':24}"}
let a = obj.key
console.log(a)  //it will log: "{'name':'bhautik','age':24}"

a = a.replaceAll('\'', "\"")
a = JSON.stringify(a)
console.log(JSON.parse(a))   

output:
[object Object] {
  age: 24,
  name: "bhautik"
}
```

Comment: The question is about a string with trailing commas.

Answer (score -2):

A JSON object stringified should always contain the object wrapped inside single quotes `'`. Yours' is wrapped inside a double quote `"`.

Since you are getting your JSON response in an unacceptable format and you cannot take that and parse directly add a single quote `'` to the first and last of the response to make it valid.
That is,
if the response you're getting is 
 `"{ "type": "object", "properties": { "hostUrl": { "type": "string", "description": "hostUrl" } } }"` 
adding single quote makes it 
 `'"{ "type": "object", "properties": { "hostUrl": { "type": "string", "description": "hostUrl" } } }"'`

Since now your object is a valid string, use the substring method and remove the wrongly placed double quotes to get a valid JSON stringified value.

Code as below:

```
let obj = '"{ "type": "object", "properties": {"hostUrl": { "type": "string", "description": "hostUrl" } }}"';
obj = obj.substring(1, obj.length-1);
console.log(JSON.parse(obj));
```

Comment: You forgot the trailing commas. The actual string in the question is `"{ "type": "object", "properties": { "hostUrl": { "type": "string", "description": "hostUrl", }, }, }"`.

Comment: @jabaa
I gave this solution assuming that the trailing commas were just added as a filler. I mean indicating a continuation of the object properties.

Mr. Zai Su
If the above mentioned isn't the use case of those trailing commas then as told by Mr. jabaa even I agree that your JSON is in a wrong format and it needs an update at the API end.

Comment: Don't make assumption. Answer the actual question with the actual string.

Comment: json was in the wrong format. i had to convert it to string then apply heavy regex on replace methods to get it right now it works fine